# HTML Table single row(tr) with td re-arranged using css into two rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to re-arrange my Table because of width constraint. **I intend to use Jquery functions on the table which target each tr to extract all the parameters related to a product, so I do not want to have nested tr's or tr's with first 3 parameters in first and last 3 in the next.**

[image: I need something like this]

How can I get it done?

```html
    <table style="width: 300px">
     <thead>
         <tr>
       <th rowspan="2">Product</th>
       <th>Category</th>
       <th>Sub Category</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Arrival Date</th>
       <th>Manufactured Date</th>
       <th>Expiry Date</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr id="productID_1">
             <td rowspan="2">Skimmed Milk</td>
             <td>Dairy</td>
       <td>Milk</td>
       <td>1 Ltr</td>
       <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
       <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
       <td>7th Jan 2018</td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="productID_2">
             <td rowspan="2">Cheddar</td>
             <td>Dairy</td>
       <td>Cheese</td>
       <td>200 Grms</td>
       <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
       <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
       <td>15th Jan 2018</td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="productID_3">
             <td rowspan="2">Vanilla Ice Cream</td>
             <td>Desserts</td>
       <td>Ice Creams</td>
       <td>100 Grms</td>
       <td>15th Jan 2018</td>
       <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
       <td>31st March 2018</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

My JQuery Code

```
$("table#customerSalesTable tbody tr").each(function(index){ 
  // Code to capture each parameter 
}
```

-- Update

As suggested by @CodeIt I do not want to split single row into tow rows and try to capture my values using class. That will require complete re-edit of a large chunk of JS code.

Comment: Have a look at http://html-tables.com/ I recommend this, It will help you create table with layouts you need quickly and easily.

Comment: @Shahil I did have a look at them but they do not help in solving my problem. There is a lot more to it. Please re-read my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery**

Each `<tr>` tag contains 7 child nodes. So wrapping child nodes 1-4 and 5-7 with separate `<tr>` tags will rearrange the cells.

*Example:*

Before:

```
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Sub Category</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Arrival Date</th>
    <th>Manufactured Date</th>
    <th>Expiry Date</th>
</tr>
```

After:

```
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Sub Category</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Arrival Date</th>
        <th>Manufactured Date</th>
        <th>Expiry Date</th>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

```js
// wrapping table headers
var e = $('th').slice(1, 4);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");
var e = $('th').slice(-3);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");

// wrapping table rows
var e = $('td').slice(1, 4);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");
var e = $('td').slice(4, 7);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");
var e = $('td').slice(8, 11);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");
var e = $('td').slice(11, 14);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");
var e = $('td').slice(15, 18);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");
var e = $('td').slice(18, 21);
e.wrapAll("<tr/>");

// you can use #productID_* to capture parameters 
var e = $('#productID_2').find('td');
console.log(e);
```

```css
td,
th {
  width: 100px !important; // specifies cell width
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Sub Category</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Arrival Date</th>
      <th>Manufactured Date</th>
      <th>Expiry Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="productID_1">
      <td>Skimmed Milk</td>
      <td>Dairy</td>
      <td>Milk</td>
      <td>1 Ltr</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>7th Jan 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="productID_2">
      <td>Cheddar</td>
      <td>Dairy</td>
      <td>Cheese</td>
      <td>200 Grms</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>15th Jan 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="productID_3">
      <td>Vanilla Ice Cream</td>
      <td>Desserts</td>
      <td>Ice Creams</td>
      <td>100 Grms</td>
      <td>15th Jan 2018</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>31st March 2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I intend to use Jquery functions on the table which target each tr to extract all the parameters related to a product, so I do not want to have nested tr's or tr's with first 3 parameters in first and last 3 in the next.

Comment: @Razvi Share the complete JQuery code in you question.

Comment: @Codelt Its the basic Jquery function `$("table#customerSalesTable tbody tr").each(function(index){ // Code to capture each parameter }` I am able to resolve everything but I need to re-arrange the table to fit on my view page.

Comment: @Codelt Updated my Question.

Comment: @Razvi You need to extract `<td>` values after rearranging the table, Right? In that case if the table is auto generated add a class to all `<td>` tags with their corresponding product name (or product id). Then you can easily to extract the details using `$(.product-name)`.

Comment: @Codelt The same thought did cross my mind but for that I will have to edit a big chunk of code. I was trying to find a better and elegant solution with CSS without disturbing my JS file.

Comment: @Codelt Dude! When I asked the question you were all over it. If I am not wrong you even down voted it. Do you have any solution or tip?

Comment: @Razvi You are wrong buddy. I never down voted your question. I don't know JQuery but anyway, I managed to rearrange the table headers. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Codelt Sorry I said that. My apologies. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Razvi Did i solve your problem? If yes, accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can display each `<tr>` as a [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead of as a table row. That will let you position each cell separately in the grid. Unfortunately, since each row is its own grid, the column widths cannot depend their contents. If they did, the columns wouldn't line up.

```css
#customerSalesTable th, #customerSalesTable td {
  border: 1px solid grey; /* visible borders */
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0; /* "border-collapse" for non-tables */
  /* "Manufactured" is too long for the cell, so */
  overflow-wrap: break-word; /* or overflow: hidden if you want. */
}

#customerSalesTable tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:               /* Row height ▼ */
    "product category subcategory quantity" auto
    "product arrival  manufacture expiry  " auto
    /25%     25%      25%         25%; /* Column widths. They don't
    have to be even, but they need to be defined. */
}

/* Classes for each <td> work too, but
   if you don't want to change the HTML, */
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(1),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(1) { grid-area: product; }
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(2),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(2) { grid-area: category; }
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(3),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(3) { grid-area: subcategory; }
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(4),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(4) { grid-area: quantity; }
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(5),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(5) { grid-area: arrival; }
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(6),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(6) { grid-area: manufacture; }
#customerSalesTable th:nth-child(7),
#customerSalesTable td:nth-child(7) { grid-area: expiry; }
```

```html
<table id="customerSalesTable" style="width: 300px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th> <!-- rowspan doesn't help now -->
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Sub Category</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Arrival Date</th>
      <th>Manufactured Date</th>
      <th>Expiry Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="productID_1">
      <td>Skimmed Milk</td>
      <td>Dairy</td>
      <td>Milk</td>
      <td>1 Ltr</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>7th Jan 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="productID_2">
      <td>Cheddar</td>
      <td>Dairy</td>
      <td>Cheese</td>
      <td>200 Grms</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>15th Jan 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="productID_3">
      <td>Vanilla Ice Cream</td>
      <td>Desserts</td>
      <td>Ice Creams</td>
      <td>100 Grms</td>
      <td>15th Jan 2018</td>
      <td>1st Jan 2018</td>
      <td>31st March 2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```